# webpack/pinax-theme-bootstrap: change backslash to forward slash in generated static link

Tags: django, webpack, pinax

When I use this configuration in webpack, that comes by default with pinax's account starter project:

```
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: projectTemplatesRoot + "_styles.html",
            templateContent: function(templateParams, compilation) {
                var link = "";
                for (var css in templateParams.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) {
                    link += "<link href='" + templateParams.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[css]  + "' rel='stylesheet' />\n"
                }
                return link;
            }
        }),
```

The following file gets generated:

`<link href='\site_media\static\css/site.css?5967f340b74047fcb05b' rel='stylesheet' />`

Same happens with the Javascript generator.

The backslashes break on firefox, which is unable to show any theming at all. The Django server shows the following request-response:

`[03/Dec/2015 15:07:02] "GET /account/login/%5Csite_media%5Cstatic%5Ccss/site.css?5967f340b74047fcb05b HTTP/1.1" 404 4258`

Note the %5C's which are backslashes, and the 404 error.
I'm on Windows, if that makes any difference w.r.t. the slashes.

**EDIT:**
Here is my full webpack.config.js:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var projectTemplatesRoot = "../../ardiff_frontend/templates/";

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    entry: {
        app: "./js/main.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "js/site.js?[hash]",
        publicPath: "/site_media/static"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|ico|jpg|svg)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/images")
                ],
                loader: "file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]"
            },
            { test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader") },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "/src/fonts"),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "../node_modules")
                ],
                loader: "file-loader?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]"
            },
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: "babel-loader", query: {compact: false} },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("css/site.css?[hash]"),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: projectTemplatesRoot + "_styles.html",
            templateContent: function(templateParams, compilation) {
                var link = "";
                for (var css in templateParams.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) {
                    link += "<link href='" + templateParams.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[css]  + "' rel='stylesheet' />\n"
                }
                return link;
            }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: projectTemplatesRoot + "_scripts.html",
            templateContent: function(templateParams, compilation) {
                var script = "";
                for (var js in templateParams.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js) {
                    script += "<script src='" + templateParams.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[js]  + "'></script>\n"
                }
                return script;
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

**EDIT 2:** Relevant part of my settings.py file:

```
# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "/site_media/media/"

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don"t put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps" "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "static")

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static", "dist"),
]
```

Comment: Tried using forward slashes in STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL ?

Comment: Hi @jpic, I posted the full file above. I don't think it goes so far as my settings.py, instead we give it the path in `publicPath` and `filename` in the config above. The slashes seem to be good here...

Comment: So, could you post your STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL settings ?

Comment: @jpic Added to the post...